# How to obtain unscrambled (decrypted) response from websocket using wss

Tags: websocket, server

From a web application I like to start a 3D Viewer app also on the same client (using localhost). As non-secure sockets (ws) are blocked by a lot of browsers I opt for secure sockets (wss). The client sets up a websocket communication with a small server app (running in the tray bar) And I do get the HTTP GET 101 protocol negotiation request in plain text, but upon sending back the correct headers the communication switches to ssl. How do I decrypt the received messages from the client to the server ? I do get a ssl message back at line:
var lorDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(lorRecString);

**Javascript at client**

```
enter code here

if (validDocCntr > 0)
{
    ShowMessage("Launching 3D Viewer...", "Normal");
    var uri = "ws://127.0.0.1:60000";

    var livMaxConnectionAttempts = 10;
    var livAttempt = 1;
    var livTmpAttempt = 1;

    // Initialize socket, sends welcome (negotiation upon protocol used)
    var websocket = new WebSocket(uri);

    // Open socket and send message
    websocket.onopen = function ()
    {
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            for(let i = 0; i<list.length; i++)
            {
                if (list[i].Path != null && list[i].Path.length > 0)
                {
                    if (list[i].Filename.length > 0)
                    {
                        ShowMessage("Opening " + list[i].Filename, "normal");
                        var typeval = "command";
                        var command = "Open3DView";
                        var file = list[i].Filename;
                        var lorJson = JSON.stringify({ type: typeval, exe_command: command, filename: file });
                        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
                        lorJson = "B";
                        var json_bytes = encoder.encode(lorJson);
                        websocket.send(json_bytes);
                        timeout(function ()
                        {
                            // Close the connection after 5 seconds
                            websocket.close;
                        }, 5000);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    // Socket error handler
    websocket.onerror = function (event)
    {
        var lorReceiveddata = event.data;
        alert("Socket error received:: " + lorReceiveddata);
    };

    // Socket message handler
    websocket.onmessage = function (event)
    {
        var lorReceiveddata = event.data;
        alert("Socket message received:: " + lorReceiveddata);
    };
    // Socket close
    websocket.onclose = function (event)
    {
        var lorReceiveddata = event.data;
        alert("Socket close received:: " + lorReceiveddata);
    }
```

**Server C# code**

```
using System.Net;
using ComLibrary;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace ClientTools
{
    public class SocketTools
    {
        Logger morLogger = new Logger();
        byte[] morBuffer = new byte[1024];
        SocketTools morSocketTools = null;
        private ArrayList m_aryClients = new ArrayList();
        string morIP = "127.0.0.1";
        const int mirPort = 60000;
        string morWelcomeMsg = "";
        Boolean mbrWelcomeReceived = false;
        SocketTools()
        {
            morWelcomeMsg = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + morIP + ":" + mirPort.ToString();
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SocketTools morSocketTools = new SocketTools();
            morSocketTools.ExecuteClient();
        }
        public async Task ExecuteClient()
        {
            string lorLoopbackAddress = morIP + ":" + mirPort.ToString();
            IPAddress lorIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(morIP);
            IPEndPoint lorEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(lorIPAddress, mirPort);
            Socket lorStateSocket = null;
            try
            {
                morLogger.Add("Starting server listening to: " + morIP + ", port: " + mirPort.ToString());

                // Create a TCP/IP socket
                lorStateSocket = new Socket(lorIPAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections
                lorStateSocket.Bind(lorEndPoint);
                lorStateSocket.Listen(2); // Maximum number of connections in the queue (2 different user sessions allowed)
                lorStateSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), lorStateSocket);
                morLogger.Add("Waiting for incoming connections...");

                // Accept a client connection
                Socket lorListeningSocket = lorStateSocket.Accept();
                morLogger.Add("Connected !");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                morLogger.Add("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);

                // Close the server socket
                if (lorStateSocket != null)
                {
                    lorStateSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    lorStateSocket.Close();
                    morLogger.Add("Server shutdown, please restart app.");
                }
            }
        }
        public void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SocketChatClient asyncState = (SocketChatClient)ar.AsyncState;
            if (asyncState != null)
            {
                byte[] recievedData = asyncState.GetRecievedData(ar);
                if (recievedData.Length < 1)
                {
                    morLogger.Add("Client " + asyncState.Sock.RemoteEndPoint + " disconnected");
                    asyncState.Sock.Close();
                    this.m_aryClients.Remove(asyncState);
                }
                else
                {
                    string lorRecString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recievedData);
                    if (lorRecString.StartsWith(morWelcomeMsg))
                    {
                        // Build response
                        morLogger.Add("Received protocol negotiation from client.");
                        if (new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^GET").IsMatch(lorRecString))
                        {
                            const string eol = "\r\n"; // HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker
                            var lorString = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").Match(lorRecString).Groups[1].Value.Trim() + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
                            byte[] lorNewBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lorString);
                            var lorHeaders = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + eol
                                            + "Connection: Upgrade" + eol
                                            + "Upgrade: websocket" + eol
                                            + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(lorNewBytes)) + eol + eol;
                            byte[] response = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(lorHeaders);
                            asyncState.Sock.Send(response, response.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                            asyncState.SetupRecieveCallback(this);
                            morLogger.Add("Send protocol confirmation to client.");
                            mbrWelcomeReceived = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        asyncState.SetupRecieveCallback(this);
                        var lorDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(lorRecString);
                        Tools lorTools = new Tools();
                        //lorTools.Call3DViewer();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void OnConnectRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            if (ar != null && ar.AsyncState != null)
            {
                Socket asyncState = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                var lorSocket = asyncState.EndAccept(ar);
                this.NewConnection(lorSocket, ar);
                asyncState.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(this.OnConnectRequest), asyncState);
            }
        }
        public void NewConnection(Socket sockClient, IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            SocketChatClient client = new SocketChatClient(sockClient, morLogger);
            this.m_aryClients.Add(client);
            client.SetupRecieveCallback(this);
            morLogger.Add("Client " + client.Sock.RemoteEndPoint + " joined");
        }

    }
```